# Get the name of an outer function from inner function in python

Tags: python

Consider the following pseudocode:

```
func1():
  func2() #func2 is called inside func1
```

My question is, in func2 can I access the name of the function it was called from? In this case, func1? Thanks!

Comment: In 99% of cases there is no need to really do something like this. Variable *names* shouldn't alter your program in any way. I would urge you to look at your problem and see if there is any other alternative.

Comment: I'm using a global error handling function to log errors, and want to retrieve the function which called the global error, hence I think this is proper for my needs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import inspect

def func2():
    cframe = inspect.currentframe()
    func = inspect.getframeinfo(cframe.f_back).function
    print 'called from ' + func

def func1():
    func2()

func2()
func1()
```

*Output:*

```
called from <module>
called from func1
```